# What exactly does CircleCI (and other CI tools) do?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci, circleci

How does CircleCI and other CI tools help ?

I am not able to fully understand the internals of these tools and how they help with faster deployment of apps.

Are these tools useful only for github based open source projects ? Since the testing requirements for every app is different how is it possible to seamlessly automate it using the CI tools ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are using Continous Integration (CI) is to have a well defined build system and always a releasable latest successfullbuild.

You can also integrate unit tests or integration tests.

I think it is not only useful for github-based projects, but also for projects with projects where more developers develop in parallel.

For more information: [Wikipedia: Continous-Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)

Answer (score 0):

CI is a developer practice which allows them to integrate code into their shared repository several times a day along with other developers in their team. 
Each time a developer checks-in code its been verified auto-build and detect errors early. 
It solves issues like

1. long and intense builds
2. spend less time in debugging
3. build more features quickly

**How it works**

CI server monitors for any changes in the code repo and starts building unit & integration tests. It assigns label for each version of build and also informs the team for a successful build or if it fails, the team fixes the issue and again starts to integrate.